# How can I make these into a batch command?

Tags: batch-file, command

How can I make a batch file to do this for all the different files in a Directory?

```
drg2sbg.exe file.drg -o file.sbg
drg2sbg.exe file.drg -t file.txt
drg2sbg.exe file.drg -b file.bmp
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%a in (*.drg) do (
 drg2sbg.exe "%%~a" -o "%%~na.sbg"
 drg2sbg.exe "%%~a" -t "%%~na.txt"
 drg2sbg.exe "%%~a" -b "%%~na.bmp"
)
```

where `%%a` is set to each name of the `*.drg` file in turn and `%%~na` extracts the name part.

(as lines in a batch file - reduce `%%` to `%` to operate directly from the prompt)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation worked perfect, took me ages looking for this solution :)